# PlatformChannel Already open error when I try to cast a second video

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I have a receiver app (V2) that works fine when you show the first video, but when you go to show a second video I get this:

[cast.receiver.platform.WebSocket] PlatformChannel Already open

I am unloading and loading the player each time. I can't see any way to explicitly ask the PlatformChannel to close. Here's the relevant code from the function that starts play:

```
this.receiverManager.start()
this.host = new cast.player.api.Host({'mediaElement':this.refs.video, 'url':source})
this.host.onError = function(errorCode) {
  console.log("Fatal Error - " + errorCode)
  if (window.player) {
    window.player.unload()
    window.player = null
  }
}

this.host.updateSegmentRequestInfo = function(requestInfo) {
  requestInfo.withCredentials = false;
}

if(!window.player) {
  window.player = new cast.player.api.Player(this.host)
}

this.receiverManager.setApplicationState('Ready To Cast');
this.protocol = cast.player.api.CreateDashStreamingProtocol(this.host)
window.player.load(this.protocol, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

We highly recommend that you move to a CAF receiver. Also, CAF has a new queueing API that will handle a playlist of videos.